# Jira SOAP WSDL missing functions

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

I am trying to automate bug creations on JIRA through C#, and I followed the instructions to produce the service needed. However, it seems there is missing a lot of vital functions. This is the WSDL produced:

```
<wsdl:definitions 
    targetNamespace="http://my_jira_server/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2"     
    xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"  
    xmlns:impl="http://my_jira_server/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" 
    xmlns:intf="http://my_jira_server/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3
Built on Oct 05, 2005 (05:23:37 EDT)-->
   <wsdl:portType name="JiraSoapService">
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="jirasoapservice-v2SoapBinding" type="impl:JiraSoapService">
       <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="JiraSoapServiceService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:jirasoapservice-v2SoapBinding" name="jirasoapservice-v2">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://my_jira_server/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I add the service reference to my project in Visual Studio 2008, I get the JiraSoapServiceClient object with a couple properties, apart from that there is nothing I can use. No login, no gets, no functions at all. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, I allowed remote API calls and ensured I had all necessary plug-ins enabled.

Comment: I see that your version of JIRA is a bit outdated. Here is an example of proper wsdl for JIRA: https://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl Have you tried to update JIRA?

Comment: My version of JIRA is 3.9.1, and I am not in a position to update JIRA. I was hoping to be able to use the SOAP API using my current version.

Comment: Personally, I start small with something I know will work. So I would use a simple Python client or Bob Swift's JIRA CLI to confirm that the JIRA instance is responding to SOAP properly. Then go for the custom C# code.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin ! Did you solved this one? If yes, then please share your answer, because I'm in similar position.

Comment: @wormhit: We had the same problem, JIRA version 3.10.1, and at least in our case a reboot fixed the empty WSDL. This is also mentioned in [this JIRA ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-8094?focusedCommentId=82529&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-82529).